# yeoman generator fails: "Cannot find module 'download'"

Tags: npm, yeoman-generator

I've uninstalled and reinstalled `yo` and `download` using npm. And switched to `node 10.28` and `node 11.14` but when I try and run a yo generator I keep getting:

```
module.js:333
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'download'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/fetch.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
```

I tried uninstalling / re-installing npm, yeoman, node, and the generator, plus googling and trying random things - nothing seemed to help.

**Solution**:

After some time fiddling - this fixed it:

```
cd /usr/local/share/npm/lib/
npm i download && npm update
```

Comment: As stated "npm i download" is the solution.

Comment: The fix you posted worked to resolve  the issue for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the latest version?

I don't know what went wrong here, but a module is missing. It might be because of the way you're changing the node version (it might change the path to node modules). Or it might be an installation error, make sure to read through the npm install logs.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on a version of node that I installed with brew and then upgraded (several months later) using `brew upgrade node`. I fixed it by running `brew uninstall --force node` to remove all the versions of node  and then running `brew install node` and `npm install -g yo generator-kraken bower grunt-cli` again. This may have happened as a result of having multiple versions of node installed, as reported by brew when I attempted to unistall node the first time (output below).

`` brew uninstall node
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/node/4.2.1... (2738 files, 36M)
node 0.10.29 is still installed.
Remove them all with `brew uninstall --force node`. ``

Answer (score 0):

"npm i download" never worked for me at all. With "npm install -g download" I solved definitely my problem followed, as suggested, by "npm update".

Comment: You can see in my answer I 'cd'd into the directory (I removed the step for about 1 minute today during an edit if you were unlucky to see it then). This is the same as doing `npm i -g`